# javascript. remove items in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, console, google-chrome-devtools

I was practicing - getting fluent with Arrays.
I created two arrays:

```
var arr  
var arr2
```

I pushed to them.
I spliced to them.
I merged them.
I removed from them.

My objective was to remove the first two indexes (carl and erich) from arr
Then put them back into the array in the first two index positions.
As you can see, I somehow inserted them as a 'Nested' array.

I have tried searching the documentation but have not found the best practice to do this.
I know it is simple.

While practicing code in the console using the following commands:

```
var arr =['carl','erich','rob','nate'];
arr
["carl", "erich", "rob", "nate"]
arr.push('joe','tim','steve');
7
arr
["carl", "erich", "rob", "nate", "joe", "tim", "steve"]
var arr2 = ['dan','fred','paul'];
arr2
["dan", "fred", "paul"]
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, arr2);

// intermediate testing commands using splice 


arr
["joe", "tim", "rob", "dan", "fred", "paul", 0, 4, "carl, erich"]  

// splice the two numbers from the array  
var removed = arr.splice(6, 4);
arr
["joe", "tim", "rob", "dan", "fred", "paul"]

// trying to insert carl, erich, nate, rob starting at index 0 

var removed = arr.splice(0, 4, ['carl','erich','nate','rob']);
arr
[Array[4]        ,"fred", "paul"
0: "carl"
1: "erich"
2: "nate"
3: "rob"
length: 4__proto__
```

Also, why are does the MDN documentation use 'remove' to insert ?

[mdn using remove to insert??](http:////developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Your mdn link is broken...

Comment: Take it one step at a time, read the docs for each method, and ask a question when a specific action you're doing doesn't give you the expected result. There's too much there to know what you want us to address. And I'm not sure what you expected `arr.push(0,4,'carl, erich');` to do.

Comment: ...and I don't know what you mean by "using remove to insert". That's very unclear.

Comment: @squint  each step is listed.  each command is followed by console output.

Comment: That doesn't insert a nested array. It inserts two numbers and a string.

Comment: Seems like the first 25 or so lines aren't related to anything you're asking. Pare your code example down to a snippet that represents a full yet minimal example of your issue.

Comment: @squint  the line below it removes the two numbers !  var removed = arr.splice(6, 4);

Comment: @squint  did are you suggested.  so i inserted those 4 items but not where i intended.  command to remove them from where they are please.